# условие для расчета положения страницы

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть `<div>`, нужно узнать начальную и конечную его координату. И при достижении этих координат осуществлять переход к этому элементу (это я знаю как сделать).

Как рассчитать формулу для определения границ элемента?

Пробовал с помощью `$(window).scrollTop и $().position()` но ничего не выходит.

Comment: Если речь о выплывающих элементах, то пример можно посмотреть здесь: http://codepen.io/Lucky/pen/doyQqL

Comment: (http://freehostblizz.tk/Nuu/slide2r.html) вот пример того что я сделал сейчас условие того что я приближаюсь к слайду такое `if (delta < 0 && $(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height()
     >= position.top && $(window).scrollTop() || delta > 0 && $(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() <= position.top && $(window).scrollTop())` я так понимаю оно далеко не идеальное и хотелось бы его улучшить. И может быть кто нибудь подскажет как убрать дерганье при резкой прокрутке